# Wordpress API returning empty meta array

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

If you hit `/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=X` on a wordpress blog it returns JSON of comments for that post ID. I am able to get results without an issue, but the `meta` is an empty array instead of having any meta values related to the comment.

I also have tried visiting `/wp-json/wp/v2/comments/X` to pull an individual comment, but that is also returning an empty `meta` array.

There is a `rating` field saved in the wp_commentmeta table and I'm expecting this to be returned so that I can display reviews from woocommerce on a 3rd party site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that WooCommerce itself has its own API which does return the meta value of rating, but they want an API key for something like fetching comments. I looked at the methods they use to build the response and they are just cycling through `get_comments()` results and then creating a new array with `rating` appended via doing `get_comment_meta($commentid, 'rating')`

I cannot rely on an API key for what I need as this is meant to be publicly available for me, so I added an API endpoint `/wp-json/wc/v2/reviews` which now does what I need.

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'comments_api_endpoint');   
function comments_api_endpoint()
{           
    register_rest_route( 'wc/v2', '/reviews/', array(
        'methods' => ['GET'],
        'callback' => 'comments_api',
    ));
}
function comments_api()
{
    $data = [];
    $reviews = get_approved_comments($_GET['id']);
    foreach($reviews as $review) {
        $data[] = [
            'author'  => $review->comment_author,
            'rating'  => get_comment_meta($review->comment_ID, 'rating', true),
            'content' => $review->comment_content
        ];
    }
    return $data;
}
```